# Django doesn't respect the maxlength widget attribute

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I have the following field in model:

```
short_description = models.CharField(max_length=205)
```

and the widget in ModelForm:

```
'short_description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': '3', 
'minlength': 250,'maxlength': 250})
```

The issue:

In HTML, input, Django adds correctly minlength value, but for the maxlength value he get the value from the model field and not the one specified in the widget.

```
<textarea name="short_description" cols="40" rows="3"  minlength="80" maxlength="205" required="" id="id_short_description"></textarea>
```

How do I "force" Django to take in consideration what is specified in the widget and not in the model field.